# error: expected `;' before '{' token - What is the cause?

Tags: c++, syntax

Here is my implementation file:

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stack>  //line 5
#include "proj05.canvas.h"

//----------------Constructor----------------//

Canvas::Canvas() //line 10
{
  Title = "";
  Nrow = 0;
  Ncol = 0;
  image[][100];  // line 15
  position.r = 0;
  position.c = 0;
}

//-------------------Paint------------------// line 20
void Canvas::Paint(int R, int C, char Color) 
{
  cout << "Paint to be implemented" << endl;
}
```

The errors I'm getting are these:

```
proj05.canvas.cpp: In function 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, 
    Canvas&)':
proj05.canvas.cpp:11: error: expected `;' before '{' token
proj05.canvas.cpp:22: error: a function-definition is not 
    allowed here before '{' token
proj05.canvas.cpp:24: error: expected `}' at end of input
proj05.canvas.cpp:24: error: expected `}' at end of input
```

These seem like simple syntax errors, but I am not sure what's wrong. Could someone decode these for me? I'd really appreciate it, thanks for your time!

---

**EDIT**

Here is the definition of Canvas in my .h file:

```
#ifndef CANVAS_H 
#define CANVAS_H 

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string> 
#include <stack> 

class Canvas
{
  public: 
      Canvas(); void Paint(int R, int C, char Color); 
       const int Nrow; 
       const int Ncol; 
       string Title; 
       int image[][100]; 
       stack<int> path; 
       struct PixelCoordinates 
       {  
         unsigned int r; 
         unsigned int c;
       } position; 
}; 

#endif
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, that's a mess, I'm sorry. Do you use <code> and </code> to enclose your text?

Comment: Please show the complete code.

Comment: Edited to fix readability. For future reference, use indentation instead of code tags to mark code sections.

Comment: @melee: `using namespace std;` in a header file is bad style - you bring the symbols from `std` into scope for everyone that includes your header. Also `int image[][100];` isn't valid C++ - you have to give the array a size here or make it a pointer (or just use a `vector`).

Comment: Thank you gf, I will remove that part. :)

Comment: Is that the whole header file? From the error, it looks like the header finishes with a definition of `operator>>` with a missing `}` at the end.

Answer (score 8):

`"proj05.canvas.h"` i bet the problem is there. may be no ; after class def

Comment: Oh, you beat me by almost a minute :). That sounds like what it is

Comment: Wouldn't it be great to have an error say 'hey, I think you may have missed a semicolon after your class definition' rather than that mess there?

Answer (score 6):

You must use `initializer list` to initialize `const-members`

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stack>  //line 5
#include "proj05.canvas.h"

using namespace std;

//----------------Constructor----------------//

Canvas::Canvas():Nrow(),Ncol() // Initializer list
{
  Title = "";
  //initialize image[][] correctly, your way is syntactically incorrect
  position.r = 0; //correction here
  position.c = 0; // and here
}

//-------------------Paint------------------// line 20
void Canvas::Paint(int R, int C, char Color)
{
   cout << "Paint to be implemented" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

**1**

```
PixelCoordinates.r = 0;
PixelCoordinates.c = 0;
```

should be:

```
position.r = 0;
position.c = 0;
```

**2**

`image` has already been declared. What is this:

```
image[][];
```

Comment: I changed PixelCoordinates.r and .c to be position.r and .c, like you said. I also changed image[][] to be image[][100] so it has a second bound, this is now identical between the two files. But it is not fixing my errors, it's quite confusing. Thanks for your input though, it is always appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you forgot to put a semicolon after your class definition. Look in `"proj05.canvas.h"`. You should see something like:

```
  class Canvas{
    ...
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that catches my eye as wrong/weird is image[][].  That does not really do anything. Also, I do not believe you can assign to constant member outside of a ctor list.

Finally, your assignment to PixelCoordinates is completely in error.  You've created a local struct definition, but have not made a member that uses it, therefore you cannot assign anything at all to it - especially the struct's title.  That would really confuse a compiler.

Comment: You're right, I realize image[][] needs a bound for at least the second bracket...I should change that. thanks. :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that line?

Answer (score 0):

Yikes.

(Not an answer to your specific problem, but...)

You should also remove the

```
using std;
```

That has no business in a .h file.
I am going to guess the oddly formatted .h file may be a problem.  It is legal for a filesystem of course, but it could be that.  Also ensure you have the ending semicolon on the class.

You need to have both dimensions filled in for the array you have (probably a horrible design to use that int he class anyway...)

Comment: Is there a better data structure to use? I am trying to store a map of characters (the 'canvas') and a two-dimensional array seemed to be the only thing to use. If there is a cleaner way to store the data I would happily change it.

Comment: If you need a map then std::map should suffice.  Do you mean map or a 2d array?

Comment: I had a similar issue when instantiating an array of strings using this syntax `string boo[] = {1, 2, 3}` and it was complaining. This answer inspired me to add `std::` in front of `string` and it will be working.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the reason for other errors is, the memeber definition `int image[][100]` is illegal. Non-static data members of the class cannot be declared with incomplete types. All dimensions of an array must be specified explicitly.